# How to get a B1/B2 Visa in a third country as a Cameroonian?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, applications, cameroonian-citizens

Please, I need clarification. I read something about Third country visa application. Can I apply for US visas from any West African nation? I am going on a West African tour to about 5 different countries, so I wanted to know if I could apply via a third country?

Comment: As a general rule (both for a US or Schengen Visa) you should apply in your main country of residence. If that country is not your country of citizenship, then that is the third country meantioned.

Comment: @Dre It would probably help if you specified your citizenship and the West African countries on your tour. You can apply from any country but it may be more difficult to qualify for a visa outside of the country where you live.
https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html  How long will you be in each country, bearing in mind the need to attend the visa interview?

Comment: @MarkJohnson, means I can apply from any other Embassy you mean, when I am on the Tour?

Comment: No, you must apply in the country you live in (not just visiting).

Comment: @Mark Johnson That is not mandatory for a US visitor visa

Comment: @Traveller, are you saying one can apply for instance, I leave cameroon and find myself in say Freetown, or Abidjan, I can apply there?

Comment: If you are a citizen of South Africa, but live in Kenya you can apply in Kenya (Third country) but not in Niagara (where you are only visiting).

Comment: For instance https://do.usembassy.gov/soliciting-u-s-tourism-visa-third-country-national/ take a good look at this line , 'Obviously residents of the Dominican Republic may apply, but even if you are on vacation or temporarily working or studying in the Dominican Republic  you can submit your application here'  This brought me to this question

Comment: From How to Apply on https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html  “You should schedule an appointment for your visa interview at the U.S. Embassy or Consulate in the country where you live. You may schedule your interview at another U.S. Embassy or Consulate but it may be more difficult to qualify for a visa outside of the country where you live.”

Comment: I'll withdraw that for the US, since it is not explicitly stated on their site. https://de.usembassy.gov/visas/tourism-visitor/tourism-visitvisa/ But with the interview will nevertheless become problematic.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can apply for a B1/B2 visa from outside your country of residence. https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html

As a general rule, you should schedule an appointment for your visa interview at the U.S. Embassy or Consulate in the country where you live. You may schedule your interview at another U.S. Embassy or Consulate, but be aware that it may be more difficult to qualify for a visa outside of the country where you live.

The possible drawbacks of doing so include:

- it may be more difficult to provide relevant supporting documents
- the wait time to attend the interview may be longer than the time you plan to / are able to stay in a particular location
- if you’re on an extended tour, it may be more difficult to prove ties to home.